# android AD not shown if testdevice is added

Tags: android, admob

```
AdView adView = (AdView)v.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice("device#")
    .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I didnt include my actual device number (idk does it have to be a secret?) but I have it. 
Anyhow this is my code and whenever i comment out the addTestDevice part i see the ads in my real device, but I dont see them when i have the addTestDevie part.
I dont think this is the way it supposed to be. My device should display the ads but ads should not be clikable. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

NB there is no value is hiding your your device ID AFAIK.

When you use addTestDevice you should see test ads. They tend to be quite different to real ads. Ie they say things like "Test ad" etc. And you should be able to click on them.